# jQuery - parent() not working within callback function

Tags: jquery, function, parent, closest

I was testing with parent() and closest(), none work within function.

**TD stays the same, no change using this method:**

```
$.get('form.php', function(data){ 
    alert(data); 
    $(this).closest('td').html('Done!'); 
});
```

**TD gets updated, this method works:**

```
$.get('form.php', function(data){ 
    alert(data); 
}); 
$(this).closest('td').html('Done!');
```

Can you please help me figure out why does `closest('td')` not working within callback function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `this` inside of the callback function has another scope than the `this` on the outside. You need to do something like this:

```
var self = this;
$.get('form.php', function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $(self).closest('td').html('Done!');
});
```

You can use jQuery's [`.proxy()`-function](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to achieve the desired effect, too, like patrick dw pointed out in his post. I recommend reading through [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).

Comment: That was quick, and it worked! I wasn't aware that `this` works differently inside of a $.get, another lesson to learn. Thank you both!

Comment: `this` works differently inside different functions. JavaScript has function scope. `this` points to the current context/scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [jQuery's `$.proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) for the second argument for `$.get()` to retain the desired value of `this`.

```
$.get('form.php', $.proxy(function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $(this).closest('td').html('Done!');
}, this));
```